# My online boyfriend ask me to do the bank transfer using his bank account because he can't access it from another country

Tags: scams, online-banking, sugar-daddy

My online boyfriend asked me to do bank transfer because he is in another country and he can't access it.So I log in to his account and I did the transaction, there was an international pin ,cot pin, and conversion code and I successfully transferred it. Then I logged out his account. But when I tried logging in again, it says the bank account is suspended. So I tried reaching out the bank and they said my IP location and address in not on Whitelist and they require me to pay the fee which is 2090 dollars. So I did pay but they ask again for another payment inorder to allow me to new transfer fund and the fee is 5000 dollars. I got suspicious so I never tried paying it again and my online boyfriend is frustrated, but I suspected him too because he ask me to pay the fee but I don't have the money and he don't have that.

Now I'm highly suspicious if my boyfriend is in cahoots with the bank and if the bank is legit or not

Comment: I removed the link so that other people don't accidentally fall into the trap. This is clearly a scam and the "boyfriend" is scamming you.

Comment: To help avoid being scammed again in the future, I would strongly recommend visiting https://consumer.ftc.gov/articles/how-avoid-scam . That's a page maintained by the US government, but the advice should be good even if you are in another country.

Comment: I hope you did not pay that first 2090 fee out of your own pocket. No one just pays a fee that high on someone else's behalf without running it by them first. That's a lot of money.

Comment: Ignoring all the other red lights, his account being suspended is your problem... how? You did what he asked you to do. If that resulted in "his" account being suspended (I'm assuming it was *not* his account, and wanted the access tied to your location, not his), *he* can pay the fee to unlock it. Frankly, this doesn't even sound like a real bank. No verification of *who* is unlocking the account; they just sell renewed access to anyone willing to fork over $2000? And a  $5000 transfer fee? How much money are you *transferring*?

Comment: You got suspicious after $5,000 but not after $2,090. The $2,090 that you lost is your own fault. @DKNguyen Of course it comes out of barbie's own pocket. How would the scam work otherwise?

Comment: @gnasher729 I was hoping for the first $2090 was supposedly paid by the boyfriend to ease the mark into it. It's one thing to suddenly see a ridiculous fee and be asked to pay for it. It's another to see someone else pay for it first. Makes something abnormal seem slightly more normal.

Comment: @gnasher729 I just don't understand why anyone would go out of their way to pay a fee that high of their own accord on the behalf of someone without even asking the other person what is up when they saw that fee in the first place. For example, if you ask me to go out and buy milk for you and it turns out the milk is $500 a jug, I am going to come back and ask if you actually want the milk. Because it's your milk and I am expecting you to pay for the milk yourself, and I don't want to be out $500 if you don't.

Comment: "because he is in another country and he can't access it."  One word: VPN.

Comment: @DKNguyen the "con" in "con artist" stands for "confidence". The scam only works if the mark trusts the scammer. If the mark trusts the scammer then these questions don't even come up.

Comment: @littleadv I dunno...even if my own mother asked me to buy a $500 jug of milk I would raise my eyebrows. Trust or not, I would at least run it by her first. But in this case it sounds like this didn't happen. That's the part that has me scratching my head. Not the fact that the payment happened but that it it sounds like the payment happened without consultation.

Comment: @DKNguyen you'd be amazed how gullible people can be. The scammers are masters of identifying people who are easily trusting, and would not even try checking whether Austria has a southern coast or Nigeria has royalty. You're saying the mark should have run it by the scammer, but maybe she did - what help would it be?

Comment: @littleadv It wouldn't have helped since the scammer could explain around it. It's more curiosity on my part about the level of diligence that was taken, even if ineffective. Because blind trust isn't the same as just not thinking.

Comment: Note that in this case -- given the "COT code" -- your "boyfriend" and the "bank" do see to be part of the same group of fraudsters. That isn't always the case; sometimes the bank is guilty of nothing more than being a bank.

Comment: I hope you live in a country where dollars aren't much, like Liberia. (2090 Liberian dollars = 13.61 US dollars)

Comment: How did you pay? The police might be able to get the money back.

Comment: @keshlam this site could really use a page like that government one, both with typical "red flags" to look for and with advice on how to identify if the situation is indeed a scam. It could be available via link right on the moment you want to ask a question tagged with [scams]

Comment: If you want to write one, standard practice on Stack Exchange is to ask the question, and then answer it yourself. Keeping track of (or rediscovering) the link, alas, is left as an exercise for the reader; SE doesn't have a real FAQ mechanism other than upvoting.

Comment: However, it would be a better service to the world at large to maintain such a document outside Stack Exchange. Easier to find, can be structured for better access, and so on.

Comment: The question has a "sugar-daddy" tag, which would typically indicate that the "boyfriend" has promised larger amounts of money. Greed, not trust or lust.

Answer (score 63):

Any time someone asks you to move their money through your account, assume it is a scam.

Any time someone asks you to log in as them, assume it is a scam.

Any time someone asks you to do them a favor and there's an unexpected fee, assume it is a scam.

Any time someone tells you that something has to happen Right Now, assume it's a scam.

Always ask yourself why they need *you* to do this for them rather than contacting someone they know better or already have a business relationship with.

Remember that anyone you know only on the Internet is still a stranger. And may be a complete fiction existing only to get you interested enough to be scammed. (And yes, this means any "internet boyfriend or girlfriend" must be considered untrustworthy, just as any other kind of penpal must, until proven otherwise. Sorry; that's the world we live in. Have fun with your online chats but do not take them seriously unless you know the person In Real Life -- and even that isn't always enough.)

Yes, there are sometimes legitimate exceptions. But they're vanishingly rare, and should be cross checked using contacts other than the ones they gave you before being trusted.

At least you got suspicious after the first $2000. It could have been worse.

Comment: ..."Any time someone tells you that something has to happen Right Now" - it IS a scam. Excepting clearly timed items like a taxi to the airport.

Comment: I wouldn't pay for a stranger's taxi to the airport unless I was willing to lose that money. Urgent does not necessarily mean important, especially when it's someone else's urgency that they shouldn't actually need your help with

Comment: (BTW, thanks, rephrased.)

Comment: For a flight, urgency is implied. All other financial transactions - all other than paying for public transport - are normally time-insensitive. Asking for urgency when it's not really reqiured is an extremely common tactic for suppressing the victim's diligence.

Comment: True. Con artists want you to react before you think about whether what you are hearing actually makes sense.

Answer (score 30):

I'm sorry but there is no boyfriend and there is no bank.

You just gave away $2,090 to an Internet stranger. I don't know how you sent this money but assume it's gone forever.

To be in cahoots implies that at least two parties are involved but your "boyfriend" and "bank" are quite likely the same entity; err, criminal.

Comment: I would dispute your last word.  It should be "criminal," not "entity."

Comment: @WGroleau Fair enough!

Answer (score -2):

You already have a good answer but this can be answered way way easier.

There is no reason to ever ask someone to login to a site because their country is blocked.    Sites have to follow regulations of countries to do business in those countries but banks/websites are not internet police.

For $5 a month (or possibly free) anyone can sign up for a reputable VPN service and can login from virtually most countries in the world.   The website does not care if they are on a VPN.

So yea its a scam and the "excuse" is pitiful as it is something that maybe would have a tiny bit of teeth 20+ years ago.

Comment: Sorry to contradict, but when you are abroad, bank can REALLY be a pain in the a$$. That what makes this scam a bit plausible. For the record, my multiple bad experiences are with french banks.

Comment: I am abroad a ton and know the restrictions from at least 3 banking websites.   Yes some make sure you login from your country and text/email you a verification.    Nothing a VPN and working cell can't solve for.   There may be restrictions on amounts but nothing to do with country.

Comment: It honestly does depend on the bank, but some of them will block all VPN services, so its not a guaranteed solve.

Comment: Also, some countries (China?) block VPNs or at least try to.  But that doesn't change the fact that OP got scammed.  It just amazes me how often I've seen warnings on TV and social media about this, and yet criminals keep doing it because people keep falling for it..

Comment: @B-K - your comment and the 3 upvotes show you the knowledge level of who actually votes and comments on the site.   No bank blocks VPN services.   Almost ALL reputable banks suggest using a service when banking - customers using VPN saves them fraud money.     I have actually never heard of a bank blocking VPN and would like you to produce ONE reputable bank that does.    Quite frankly comments like yours is why I quit using SE.   Just nonsense.    And again yes banks may block you on VPN if you are porting through another country... but I already covered that.

Comment: I banked with multiple US banks that wouldn't allow me to log in into their online portals while I was traveling abroad, it can most definitely be a nuisance in some situations. Also, many geo-filters have pretty decent VPN detection.

Comment: @blankip Maybe all reputable banks where you live recommend a VPN but thats not the entire world, so you can't just make blanket statements saying that something never happens. For the record, here in Australia, I or my friends/family have had issues connecting to 3 of the 4 biggest banks by a VPN (no not porting through another country, just connecting from Australia to Australian servers), and the only reason I can't comment on the fourth is that I don't know anyone with an account there. I'm sure there are many more banks around the world with similar situations...

Comment: ...And further, VPNs are not necessarily seen by banks as saving them money. Sure they might secure legitimate users connections, but they also mask illegitimate users, eg. someone who has just scammed or otherwise acquired login credentials

Comment: Ok, as usual, experience differs and neither answer will be right 100% of the time. The points I raised should apply whether or not VPN is an acceptable workaround -- asking you to do something that will cost you money or put you in a questionable legal position is still a screaming red flag, and asking you to go to a website you've never heard of should be viewed with extreme prejudice.

Comment: @keshlam - the idea that banks block vpn services is LUDICROUS.   I asked for ONE example.   Yes this is getting talked about and voted up on a personal finance site.    Embarrassing for the site.   Comments above... are why people with knowledge don't answer questions on SE.    (I used to set up banks cloud networks for years... but what do I know)

Comment: @B-K - give me the banks names.   I don't believe you.   At all.

Comment: Whether you believe this or not is orthogonal to the question we're trying to address, of how to recognize it as a scam. This is certainly a valid question to challenge them on, subsumed in "why do they need _you_ involved".

Comment: @blankip one example is Paypal (not technically a bank, I know). At leat, it was there policy 10 years ago when I was in Indonesia. Also, I'm not sure in what strate of society you are living, but in my world, banks don't apply clear rules. They just block you for some blanket reason and you have to deal with it.

Comment: @Madlozoz - paypal is not a bank... at all.   I just asked for one example of a real bank doing this...    Both people that made comments said they had many but can't write one name.