# Foreign bank transactions

Tags: scams, hong-kong

I was asked to manage an account on line, since the owner was travelling,  and I was given a log in information, first and second transactions went okay, since it was domestic transfers, but when I was asked for the 3rd transfer, it required me COT code, And I have to pay, the online bank has no phone number, only chat.. and it says, I have to pay $4,500 for th COT code, so I said, what can’t you just deduct it on the owners account, and the answer was, Oh, I can detect your IP location,,,

Comment: If someone randomly asks you to manage a bank account, it is a scam. Period. Unless they're your brother, and even then I'd be suspicious.

Comment: See also https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/153875/my-online-boyfriend-ask-me-to-do-the-bank-transfer-using-his-bank-account-becaus/153878#153878

Answer (score 2):

First Google search result for "COT code" showed that it's commonly used in advance pay scams. [This Money SE post](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/100166/i-was-asked-for-a-cot-code-to-transfer-money-to-my-account-is-this-a-scam) dives deeper into this as well. It sounds very likely to be a scam.