Why someone that I've been dating for the last 4 months then asks me to make a transfer for him?
Why someone that I've been on a relationship foe the last 4 months was asking me to log in into his bank account and make a wire transfer to another account because he has no network where he lives (south Korea), I've made 2 tranfers and for the 3rd one the account was on hold of course i contacted the bank by chat and they told me it was because the account was login in another country ( united states) and the only way to unfreeze the account its to make a payment of 3 thousand dollars by cash app. And then after the account is activated they will refund the money to the bank account that was on hold.

Have you ever met this person? You're being scammed.

Does this answer your question? I am asked to complete my withdrawal transaction with COT fee of 1200 dollars

Sympathy, but this person is not your friend. If you have given them any personal data, treat it as an identity theft attempt and invalidate as much of that information as possible. Hopefully you can get away before serious damage is gone.

A distant relative, woman in her 70s, always finds really attractive men on the internet who are romantically very interested in her. She always dumps them instantly when they ask for money :-) She loves the attention she gets, but she isn’t stupid.

@gnasher729 Has she ever considered asking for money first?

No, it’s not about the money. It’s about the attention she gets. One was a very attractive looking airplane pilot (saw a photo, he was really good looking), and she just enjoyed it. As long as it lasted.

See also https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/153875/my-online-boyfriend-ask-me-to-do-the-bank-transfer-using-his-bank-account-becaus

Unless you have interacted with this person substantially in person (not by chat or video or text) then you are being scammed. Break off all contact. If you have given out any personal information assume it is now public knowledge and will be used against you. If you gave out any passwords change them immediately.
It is an unfortunate fact that many scammers are prepared to act like they are "in a relationship" with someone online for many months before finally asking for money. The large amounts of money that people are willing to give to people they think love them makes it worthwhile putting the months of effort in. (Although they are also interacting with many 'lovers" online at once, so it is not as much effort as all that.)
No real bank requires you to pay up front like that. The linked answer will explain the details of the scam.
You can read up on how romance scammers work in this article or plenty of others.

This is most likely either an advance-fee scam or a money-mule scam.
If you're being asked to pay money to be able to access your money, it's nearly always a scam. Are you sure that you're dealing with the real bank and not someone impersonating a bank employee? Are you sure that the bank itself is legitimate?
Also, why can't he transfer his own money? The whole "I don't have network where I am" is pretty weak. The Internet works just fine in South Korea (as do cell networks). Also, if what he's saying is really true, how is he contacting you?
Even if the bank account is a real account with real money (which is questionable), it's likely stolen. Scammers routinely recruit people to unknowingly help them transfer stolen money (see the link I provided on money-mules).
